# Did Apple change the .mobileprovision file format, and how can I view the current format?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-provisioning

I'm finding many articles on the web where it is implied that you can view the .mobileprovision file contents in a text editor.  For example, this [Urban Airship post](https://support.urbanairship.com/customer/portal/articles/60710-can-t-get-a-device-token-%22no-valid-aps-environment-entitlement-%22-seen-in-console):

> When push notifications are enabled for an app, the aps-environment key will appear in the .mobileprovision file specifying the provisioning profile:

```
<key>Entitlements</key>
<dict>
    <key>application-identifier</key>
...
```

However the mobilprovision files I have (obtained within the last few days) contain 466 1/2 rows of 8 groups of 4 hex digits, (e.g. `4851 3842 4176 2845 0a09 01a2 404d 4382`).  How can I view this type of file?

Comment: For the curious, the first few bytes decoded to ASCII to `HQ8B Av(E` then head into control-characters..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are using a text-editor that is a bit too clever for you :D.

Your editor finds out that the file actually is binary and shows it as a hex-dump - for example Sublime 2 does it that way. Open that same file using TextEdit. You will see a couple of lines of binary garbledegock and then some plain-text (XML) that should contain the information you are looking for.

However, do **not** edit that file using TextEdit, that will render it unusable!

Comment: Yes I am using Sublime 2!  I haven't been using it that long and didn't realize it would do this kind of thing... TextEdit does show the XML content... thanks

Answer (score 41):

Provisioning Profiles are encoded. To decode them and examine the XML you can use this via command line:

`security cms -D -i #{@profilePath}`

where `#{@profilePath}` is the filepath to your .mobileprovision file.

A fuller Ruby example is:

```
require 'plist'
profile = `security cms -D -i #{@profilePath}`
xml = Plist::parse_xml(profile)
appID = xml['Entitlements']['application-identifier']
```

Answer (score 16):

If you want Sublime Text 2 to be able to read .mobileprovision profiles this is the setting

```
"enable_hexadecimal_encoding": false,
```

Comment: You would want that specifically for that filetype, I'ld recon - not globally.

Answer (score 12):

You can use openssl to output the contents of the signed profile.

```
openssl smime -in /path/to/your.mobileprovision -inform der -verify
```