# Tool for displaying the contents of a Provisioning Profile (.mobileprovision) file?

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, xcodebuild, ios-provisioning

I have the dreaded

```
Code Sign error: No matching provisioning profiles found: This product type
must be built using a provisioning profile, however no provisioning profile
matching both the identity “Foo, Inc” and the bundle identifier “com.foo.Bar”
was found.
```

... error emanating from `xcodebuild` (by way of [Shenzhen](https://github.com/nomad/shenzhen)) but I think it's lying to me. Is there a tool I can use to see what certificates and bundle identifiers are included in the `.mobileprovision` file I'm passing in? I've run `strings` on it and it looks right, but it's hard to tell exactly.

Comment: Seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10988998/did-apple-change-the-mobileprovision-file-format-and-how-can-i-view-the-curren)?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can try the following command: 
`security cms -D -i some.mobileprovision` but hard to tell if it will be helpful.

Comment: Did you get that from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10988998/did-apple-change-the-mobileprovision-file-format-and-how-can-i-view-the-curren)?

Comment: Heh, no ;] I've taken it from the tool I was developing some time ago: https://github.com/apphance/Apphance-MobilE-Build-Automation, from this class exactly: https://github.com/apphance/Apphance-MobilE-Build-Automation/blob/master/src/main/groovy/com/apphance/flow/executor/IOSExecutor.groovy

Comment: OK cool.  The question is a dupe, though.

Comment: Yeah, 'tis. Annoyingly the question it's a dupe of has the wrong answer marked as accepted.

Comment: @RobertAtkins That's because the correct answer was given almost a year later.

Comment: Not sure how this is is being talked as the wrong answer, as it is the correct answer.

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried ProvisionQL?

https://github.com/ealeksandrov/ProvisionQL

It provides the QuickLook feature for provisioning profiles!

[image: provisioning profie example]

Check out more screenshots for how it work: https://github.com/ealeksandrov/ProvisionQL/blob/master/screenshots.md